# Debugging my checksum function

Tags: scheme

We have this code

```
(define (checksum-2 ls)
  (let ([x (reverse ls)])
    (cond
      [(null? ls) 0]
      [else (+ (*  (length ls) (car x)) (checksum-2 (cdr x)))])))
```

It reverses this list

```
'(4 6 7 5 6)
```

It's suppose to return 87 but it returns 80. Can anyone help us debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, this function will return

```
5 * 6 + 4 * 4 + 3 * 5 + 2 * 6 + 1 * 7 = 80
```

This is because at each stage, it takes the first element of the reversed list (i.e. the last element of the list) and multiplies it by the list length, and adds it to the result of calling `checksum-2` on the *reversed* list. The list is then reverse again, so the next element to be added is the one that was originally at the *front* of the list (which is `4` in this case).

What you want to do is reverse the list *once*, and then work with the reversed list from then on. To do this you can use a helper function:

```
(define (chksum ls)
  (chksum-helper (reverse ls)))

(define (chksum-helper ls)
  (cond
    ((null? ls) 0)
    (else (+ (* (length ls) (car ls))
             (chksum-helper (cdr ls))))))
```

Now you only have to reverse the list once, which is a big win in efficiency. To clean up the code you can factor the definition of `chksum-helper` inside the definition of `chksum`, getting something like this:

```
(define (chksum ls)
  (define (chksum-helper x)
    (cond
      ((null? x) 0)
      (else (+ (* (length x) (car x))
               (chksum-helper (cdr x))))))
  (chksum-helper (reverse ls)))
```

I renamed the argument to `chksum-helper` from `ls` to `x` to prevent confusion, but you don't actually have to do this - it would work just as well if you left it as `ls`. This is about as compact as you're going to get it.

Comment: so this?
(define (checksum-2 ls)
  (let ([x (reverse ls)])
    (cond
      [(null? ls) 0]
      [else (+ (*  (length ls) (car x)) (checksum-2 (cdr ls)))])))

Comment: When doing that our answer is 90 then. :\

Comment: Sorry, my fault. See corrected version. In fact, I'm going to update this answer a bit, so keep checking back.

Comment: Thank you! it still gives us 90, we've been working on this since 11pm US eastern time and its 4:30 am right now :\

Comment: Glad to help. A tip for future questions - I know it seems very important *to you* that you've been working on the problem set for five hours, but to everyone else it just looks like whining. You're likely to get better answers to your questions if you don't whine.

Comment: Haha, it's just that I find scheme pointless for me to learn as I need java in the field that I want to go into. And we've been going at this assignment for almost 12 hours. I really appreciate the help though!

Comment: @DwayneR.Fortune I left you a comment regarding Scheme on one of your other questions. It is *far* from pointless to learn. As Eric S Raymond said: "Lisp [the family that Scheme is part of] is worth learning for the profound enlightenment experience you will have when you finally get it; that experience will make you a better programmer for the rest of your days."

Comment: Keep in mind that you probably won't end up in the field you currently want to go into. And if you do end up there, by the time you get there, they might not even be using Java. The only thing you can count on is change.

Comment: To be a bit of the "grumpy guy": the fact that you started at 11pm and expected to finish overnight is not a good sign.  Please treat the subject of programming with more respect.  The fact that you consider this problem pointless is another point against you: frankly, a competent programmer will look at this problem, and see what it's trying to compute in a few moments.  But it takes a LOT of practice to get to that level.  There is value in "finger exercises".  You're doing yourself a disservice by discounting them.